# Where to access the WGCNA tutorial documents: Horvath lab site down

Tags: wgcna

I am currently using the WGCNA package for some analysis and it seems the Horvath lab site is down. Does anyone know of anywhere else I can access the tutorial documents?

Comment: Thank you Peter. Could you also please post the PDF for the FAQs that was originally on the website? They don't seem to be in the dropbox folder. There is a lot of useful tips on there that you and other have referenced to before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apologies for the web site trouble, we are working with UCLA to restore the web pages. In the meantime, I uploaded the tutorials to Dropbox at https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/4vqfiysan6rlurfo2pbnk/h?rlkey=thqg8wlpdn4spu3ihjuc1kmlu&dl=0. I suggest downloading the entire folder, unzipping and opening the file index.html in a browser. You should see a stripped down but usable version of the web page and all tutorial sections should be accessible.

Comment: That's great - thanks Peter

Comment: Might I suggest using GitHub rather than Dropbox? It's an influential package after all, things like that should be permanently available irrespective of private and academic hosting services.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking into a better and more permanent home for the entire package, GitHub is certainly a candidate...

Comment: Would it be possible to get the FAQs section added to the dropbox folder also ?

Comment: Any updates @PeterLangfelder?

Comment: No, no updates yet :(